# MVC4 Bundle with a Custom-Attribute on Link-Element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I'm using `System.Web.Optimization.Bundle` to bundle all my stylesheets. Is there a way to extend the Bundle Class to include custom attributes to get a following output?

```
<link href="/Content/Css/view.css" rel="stylesheet" data-class="en"/>
```

Here in the link element is the `data-class="en"` included:

```
bundles.Add(new CustomStyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include("~/content/css/en/view.css"));
```

Comment: Instead of data attributes you could package bundles for different classes `~/Content/css/en, ~/Content/css/xx, etc` then conditionally include the appropriate bundle.

Answer (score 0):

[mvc4 bundle, how it is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844289/mvc4-bundle-how-it-is-working)

Can be include it like this. No need to create a custom bundle.

```
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: how does this expand for debug builds?